# group the list of listmap by keys and collect all the values of common keys

Tags: scala

I have a list of ListMap object eg.

```
List(Listmap("a" ->"abc","b" -> "xyz"),Listmap("a"->"wqw","b" -> "sds"))
```

I want to have the output as:

```
Map("a" ->"abc","wqw",b -> "xyz","sds")
```

I want to basically group the list of listmap by keys and collect all the values of common keys.

Comment: What is `Listmap`? `b -> "xyz","sds"` is not well defined. Did you mean `b -> Seq("xyz","sds")`?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you come across? There is a `groupMap` method that is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Please do not ask people spending their free time to solve your problem "ASAP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have:

```scala
val input = List(Map("a" ->"abc","b" -> "xyz"),Map("a"->"wqw","b" -> "sds"))
```

You can do something like:

```scala
input.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]])((m1, m2) => {
  m2.foldLeft(m1)((currMap, kvp) => {
    currMap.get(kvp._1).fold {
      currMap.updated(kvp._1, Seq(kvp._2))
    } { currValue =>
      currMap.updated(kvp._1, currValue :+ kvp._2)
    }
  })
})
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/yUdF621PQaq2k8hfvmT9og).

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List(ListMap("a" ->"abc","b" -> "xyz"),ListMap("a"->"wqw","b" -> "sds"))

list.flatten.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

This gives

```
Map(a -> List(abc, wqw), b -> List(xyz, sds))
```